# 3D ipelets for ipe

Tags: 3d, technical-drawing, ipe

Is there an ipelet to draw 3D objects in Ipe?

I know there's one for plotting 2D functions, but I didn't find any in 3D.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is still no IPELET for 3D figures. The way out of this problem is to study about Tikz and face the challenges.

Comment: for complicated 3D figures, Asymptote is a suitable choice!